# ArcGIS 10 MapControls in MS Access, can it be done?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, ms-access, mapcontrol

In the past (9.3 ArcGIS) I was able to develop forms in MS Access where I could drop a MapControl on and have GIS functionality all within Access as long as ArcMap was installed on the same machine.

I now have ArcGIS 10 and Office 2003 and when I start Access go to  VB editor and create a form I am unable to add a MapContol, it says I do not have the appropriate license.  I've had a search on the ESRI website and Help and I have not found a clear answer.

Am I correct in understanding that they have changed something behind the scenes with regards to the MapControl, one cannot simply use it anymore? I've tried dropping an ESRI LicenseControl on the form and I get the same message rejecting me as I have no license to use the LicenseControl!

It would be good if someone clarifies this and explain how one can embed a MapControl into a MS Access form?

Comment: Here is the link to another thread on a similar subject : http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/46800-MS-Access-2010-and-ArcMap-10?p=159965#post159965

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map control was a relic from the vb6 days. Since arcgis10 doesn't support vb6, it's no wonder that you can't use the map control in vba. I remember a bug about this misleading error, but I no longer remember the NIM.

Answer (score 4):

With version 10 you need to explicitly initialize the license for the software; so that it knows what level to look for and what to check out. You can see the [support doc](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00420000006z000000) to get you started. So you will want to have in your form a string to activate your license; then when you dispose of the form to return the license.
This [.Net sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Check_Out_Extension_License_Snippet/004900000090000000/) gives you the major lines you need to look for.

Comment: David, Thanks for replying. I note you offer a .Net solution but I'm talking about Office and VBA.

I had a go at creating an object of type IAOIntialize and calling the Initialize Method in the onLoad event of the form as shown below:

Dim p As IAoInitialize
Set p = New AoInitialize
p.Initialize esriLicenseProductCodeArcView

But when I added a MapControl I get a slightly different warning "This control requires an ArcGIS Engine Developer Kit license". Is this free? 

If not, does this mean ESRI have taken away the ability to embed MapControls in Office Applications?

Comment: With VBA you will find very little ability anymore; you may seen the need to write a Access-AddIn to do what you seek. And no, you don't need to have ArcEngine, if you are doing this on a machine with ArcMap(ArcView/ArcEditor/ArcInfo) installed, then you can just initialize the license for the appropriate platform.